# The focus event is not fired in Firefox with Shift+Tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, iframe, onfocus

See full code and play with it here: https://plnkr.co/edit/qJ7eiJewb0hmj8wF?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview

Pseudo code:

```
<div parent focusable>
    <iframe>
        #document
        <input textbox>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Click to focus to the textbox, then `Shift+Tab`

- In Chrome: the focus is moved directly from the `textbox` to the `parent`
- In Firefox: the focus is moved from the `textbox` to the `iframe`, you will have to `Shift+Tab` a second time to move the focus to the `parent`

Question: How to replicate the same behavior `Shift+Tab` of Chrome in Firefox?

I can replicate the behaviour of `Tab` of Chrome in Firefox but I'm unable to replicate the behaviour of `Shift+Tab`
because no focus event is fired when the focus moved to the `iframe` (in case of `Shift+Tab`).

Note: Paypal solved this problem in their payment forms:

https://codepen.io/braintree/pen/ZWPpPG

but I'm unable to find out where did they do the magic

Comment: I could not get this to fire an actual focus event for the child document's html element (might need tabindex for that to work?) But the blur event of the input field had its relatedTarget set to the html element, so you could check for that - and then set focus on the parent window yourself.

Comment: In Chrome [shift]+[tab] moves the focus back onto your div element. Since you mentioned PayPal, I assume you need this in a cross-origin context? Then you won't be able to focus a specific element in the parent window, only the parent window itself. If PayPal manages this, then I suppose they probably do this via the JS SDK that gets embedded into the parent page - then the iframe can communicate with the parent via `postMessage`, and tell it to set the focus on one of its own elements.

Comment: it is true I need cross-origin communication, but it is not a problem. Let say we have the same origin as in my example and I can find several way to capture the Shift+Tab event, then I will need to focus the "previousely tabbed element", but I have no idea which one? In my example it was the "parent div", but we might have a very complex page outside the iframe, and I don't know where should I put the focus after the Shift+Tab

Comment: in this example of paypal https://codepen.io/braintree/pen/ZWPpPG. Please open it in Firefox! then we can insert a checkbox between CardNumber and ExpiryDate. Then focus on the ExpiryDate (which is inside an iframe) and then Shift+Tab => Paypal will move the focus to our checkbox!! how did they know the focus should be move to our checkbox?

Comment: That is not _one single_ iframe - each of the form _fields_ there lives inside its own iframe. So in terms of _"how did they know the focus should be move to our checkbox?"_ - by picking the first focusable element before the current field's iframe, I would suppose.

Comment: it seem work https://plnkr.co/edit/1ZnGXVoj1Qforq9q?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview (not perfect through)